# How to set the position of RadConfirm dialogue box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

i have an asp.net webappliction , i have used some telerik controls in my webaplilction\

In Javascript i used following RadConfirm dialoguebox.

```
radconfirm(msg + queMsg, linkButtonCallbackFn, 430, 140, null, "Confirm");
```

i just want to know that how to set the position of Confirm dialogue box on the screeen ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

The object returned by the radconfirm invocation above is ultimately a RadWindow (see: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-dialogs-confirm.html). Using this logic you would be able to update the location of the window using the RadWindow API (see: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html).

```
var wdw = radconfirm(msg + queMsg, linkButtonCallbackFn, 430, 140, null, "Confirm");
wdw.moveTo('100px','100px');
```